# how to find the SoapAction in web service in netbeans

Tags: android, web-services

can somebody help

I make web service in NetBeans but I cannot find soapAction.
I want use it to connect my android application in eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest solution for my question about Ksoap in Android

```
static final String ADDRESS = "http://10.0.2.2";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "amir";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://abc/";
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME;
private static final String URL = ADDRESS + ":8080/Test/myaccount?WSDL";
```

Answer (score 1):

let say your package is "com.android" and method name is "yourmethod" then soapAction will be-

```
Private String SoapAction="http://android.com/yourmethod"
```